# Is there any way to submit an image with specific stage to GCR?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-multi-stage-build

I want to submit an image with specific stage that i specified in dockerfile to GCR, how can i do this?

Or may be there is a way so i can push a local image to GCR?
something like this:

`docker build --target local -t my-local-image .` 
`gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/my-local-image --image my-local-image`

Answer (score 0):

To push any local image to Container Registry using Docker or another third-party tool, you need to first tag it with the registry name and then push the image.

The following factors might impact uploads for large images:

**Upload time** :Any request sent to the Container Registry has a 2 hour timeout limit. If you authenticate to the Container Registry using an access token, the token expires after 60 minutes. If you expect your upload time to exceed 60 minutes, use a different authentication method.

**Image size** :Container Registry uses Cloud Storage for each registry's underlying storage. Cloud storage quotas and limits apply to each registry, including the 5 TB maximum size for an object in storage.

Pushing an image requires one of the following [Cloud Storage roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles), or a role with the same permissions:

**1.Pushing the first image to a registry in your project** :
Role: Storage Admin (roles/storage.admin) at the Google cloud project level. The predefined Owner role includes these permissions.The first time you push an image to a registry host in your project (such as gcr.io), Container Registry creates a storage bucket for the registry. The Storage Admin role has the necessary permissions to create the storage bucket.

**2.**Pushing images to an existing registry in your project**** :This role has permission to push and pull images for existing registry hosts in your project. For example, if your project only contains the gcr.io registry, a user with the Storage Legacy Bucket Writer role can push images to gcr.io but cannot push images to asia.gcr.io.

Refer to documentation on [Pushing and Pulling images](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) for more detailed information.